# TypeScript typeGuard in if statement does not apply

Tags: typescript

I have a custom type guard that should tell TS if something is of type B. Unfortunately, the type guard does not transfer to the if() and still thinks its an A, instead of a B.

```
function test(foo: A) {
    if(isB(foo)) {
        console.log('foo', foo);
    }
}

function isB(foo: A): foo is B {
    return foo.type === FooType.B
}

interface A {
    type: FooType
}

interface B {
    type: FooType
}

enum FooType {
    A, B
}
```

Even hovering over the console log, VSCode tells me that that foo is A, even if in that if statement it was verified to be B. Why?

Comment: that's because the interfaces are just like each other. so there is no difference if it is A or B. you can simply make them different by adding a property to one of them. then you will see the foo becomes B

Comment: however, in a real project, this might be a better solution for such a situation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4ChkHJgCeADhAFzIBiA9rQCpkQDcuAvrrjAK4gJhgtEEQgYwAChj0q6LAEpkeQsmAwJwDKin15i5SsIJhGWgBsIAOjO0A5hIDk02g4A0yZ-LYrOnbnwEhEU1tZ1lMCHkqZ1UMNCV8QigIMB4oEWdLEnJkAF58mnomcktUDi5QSFhEFABBBJVsykLGZktatj9K6HgkeIMCJqo6VpLUTq4IEB4AWxbinESCWvcy9iA

Comment: @Arashjahanbakhshan Why is adding a custom string property to each type to check for better than adding a general type property to all types you want to check for, that holds a TypeEnum to check against? Both try to do the same thing, but one has a finite list of all types in one place, while the other clutters random strings all over the place.

Comment: May I know a real use case of your need? There is not a rule to say which is good or which is better. it all depends on your use case

Comment: Do you ever want to the `type` property of an `A` to be `FooType.B` or vice versa? If not then you need [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXgQOW) so `A | B` is a discriminated union. Can you articulate why you'd prefer `A` and `B` to be structurally identical instead? I don't see telling the compiler that an `A` uses `FooType.A` and `B` uses `FooType.B` as "cluttering random strings all over the place". I mean, it would be easier to make house keys if they were all identical, but the need to have different keys for different locks isn't generally seen as "cluttering random keys all over the place".